# Android - exchanging System. currentTimeMillis() for SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - what are the implications

Tags: android, java-time, system-clock, current-time

i have tried to write the following function which given a time in the future will tell me how many milliseconds until that time:

```
fun millisFromNow(futureTime: Long): Long {
    val now = Date(System.currentTimeMillis())
    val endDate = Date(futureTime * 1000L)
    return (endDate.time - now.time)
}
```

but the user can change the  system clock and then currentTimeMillis will not be accurate .....  instead [could i use uptimeMillis](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/SystemClock#uptimeMillis()) :

```
fun millisFromNow(futureTime: Long): Long {
        val now = Date(SystemClock.uptimeMillis())
        val endDate = Date(futureTime * 1000L)
        return (endDate.time - now.time)
    }
```

it seems it will work on almost all devices since 2004 on android right ? am i using it correctly in this fashion ?  because currentTimeMillis is epoch time but uptimeMillis is time since last boot and assumes JVM is running. so to me this code does not make sense.  ?  im just using this function to start a countdownTimer so i just call it once.

update: just replacing it gives the wrong value. just system.currentTimeMillis is giving right countdown. what can i replace it with for security sake  so i can get the right millisec countdown between now and a time in the future

Comment: Not knowing Android, I suspect that i using `uptimeMillis`, the user can reboot the device to have the counter start over. Maybe you can get a reliable time from the internet? [How to get network provided time in android programmatically](https://www.xspdf.com/resolution/58403231.html). Search for more.

Comment: that s a good idea to fetch it from the net